# How to ignore inline DTD when parsing XML file in Java

Tags: java, xml, sax, dtd

I have a problem reading a XML file with DTD declaration inside (external declaration is solved). I'm using SAX method (javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser). When there is no DTD definition parsing looks like for example StartEement-Characters-StartElement-Characters-EndElement-Characters...... So there is characters method called immediately after Start or End element and thats how I need it to be. When DTD is in file parsing schema changes to for example StartElement-StartElement-StartElement-Characters-EndEement-EndEement-EndEement. And I need Characters method after every element. So I'm asking is there any way to prevent change of parsing schema?

My code:

```
SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();   
factory.setValidating(false);  

SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
XMLReader reader = parser.getXMLReader(); 

reader.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/validation", false);
reader.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-dtd-grammar", false);
reader.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);
reader.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities", false);
reader.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities", false);
reader.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/use-entity-resolver2", false);   
reader.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/validation/unparsed-entity-checking", false);
reader.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/resolve-dtd-uris", false);
reader.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/validation/dynamic", false);
reader.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/validation/schema/augment-psvi", false);

reader.parse(input);
```

There is XML file that I'm trying to parse [link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/16385374/problem.xml) (its  link on my dropbox).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that the nodes that were previously being reported to the `characters()` callback are now being reported to the `ignorableWhitespace()` callback. The simplest solution might be to simply call `characters()` from `ignorableWhitespace()`.

This is what the spec has to say about [`ignorableWhitespace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/xml/sax/ContentHandler.html#ignorableWhitespace%28char%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29):

> Validating Parsers must use this method to report each chunk of
>   whitespace in element content (see the [W3C XML 1.0 recommendation,
>   section 2.10](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-white-space)): non-validating parsers may also use this method if they
>   are capable of parsing and using content models.

In other words, if there is a DTD, and if you are not validating, then
it's up to the parser whether it reports whitespace in element-only
content models using the `characters()` callback or the
`ignorableWhitespace()` callback.